# Matlab - Search for specific coordinate points within boundary returned by bwboundaries()

Tags: matlab, coordinates, boundary

I am trying to search for a specific coordinate point (I want the x value for all coordinates in the boundary that have y=constant). Because the variable returned from bwboundaries() is weird, I'm having a lot of difficulties implementing the algorithm.

Here's what I have so far:

```
[B,L] = bwboundaries(img_cutB_filled,8,'noholes');  %Get boundaries from image 'img_cutB_filled'
for k = 1:length(B)
   boundary = B{k};
   ind=find(boundary(:,2)==y_middle_right);   %find indices of coordinate points which y=constant
   x_middle_right=min(boundary(ind,1));       %get x value
   if(isempty(x_middle_right))                
       x_middle_right=1;                       %if no coordinate found set x to 1
   end
   plot(x_middle_right,y_middle_right,'r.', 'MarkerSize',20,'LineWidth',5);
   
end
```

All I get is x value sthat make no sense, for example for y= 328, I have the following boundary:
[As you can see there are two points with y=328](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUPP3.png)

And I get:

[A x value of 20?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44NfN.jpg)

Any help is welcomed and if I wasn't clear please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use boundaries for this.

`p = img_cutB_filled(328,:)` is the line where you want to find the first and last pixel in. `find(p,1,'first')` returns the index of the first set pixel, and `find(p,1,'last')` returns the last one. Those are the two points you’re looking for.

Comment: Since I'm dealing with QR code images sometimes the result given by your aproach would be wrong, that's why I'm using boundaries. See example ![sample image](https://prnt.sc/Rk980tUEBuv0)

Comment: @Rafael No, this approach gives the leftmost and the rightmost set pixel on the line, not any other boundaries. If you try this and it doesn't work, edit your question to include a [mre], so that we can more clearly see what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You are correct, I overlooked that your solution uses the filled image so the "holes" in the qr code won't be a problem. Thanks!